# React error Uncaught TypeError: _howler2.default is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, howler.js

I am attempting to import [Howler.js](https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js) into a small React app. I've installed Howler.js in my `node_modules` with `npm install howler --save-dev`. In my `app.js` I import it with

```
import Howler from 'howler';
```

But then when I attempt to instantiate it with

```
let sound = new Howler({
    src: ['test.mp3']
});
```

I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: _howler2.default is not a constructor

I know there are wrappers for react (e.g. [this one](https://github.com/thangngoc89/react-howler)) but I'd like to get it working without if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That package has a UMD bundle and is setting [`exports.Howler`](https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js/blob/master/dist/howler.js#L2173) so you need to do

```
import { Howler } from 'howler'
```

Comment: Thanks - but I still get an error (slightly different): Uncaught TypeError: _howler.Howler is not a constructor

Comment: found this https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js/issues/603#issuecomment-242503206